# vs code can't replace using regex group references under PCRE2 mode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, pcre

I'm trying to replace my std stl usage to EASTL and since i have a lot of cpp/h files, i'm relying in 'Search in Files' option of vs-code, with the following pattern:

`((?<=#include \<)([^\/(.h)]+?)(?=\>))`

This matches completely fine in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/4b9us), in both match and replace and in vs code as well but needs the option of PCRE2 engine being enabled due backreferences use.

Trying to reference the matching group #1 using `$1` under Search sidebar view simply doesn't work, and just adds "$1".

[image]

But if i search & replace with the same input for each file manually, it works as intended.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `\1` instead of `$1`?

Comment: Already did, nope. Should i fill this issue as a bug?

Comment: Do a simple find and replace such that the regex includes a capturing group and see if the back-reference works that way,

Comment: Already did it when i wrote this question, it works as intended (Check last screenshot)

Comment: I meant a simple search without involving lookrounds from **sidebar**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: The bug which prevented `replace` from working properly with lookarounds has been fixed, see [capture group in regex not working](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81129).  It is working in the Insider's Build and will presumably be included in **v1.39**.

However, your regex:

`((?<=#include \<)([^\/(.h)]+?)(?=\>))` should be changed to:

`((?<=#include <)([^\/(.h)]+?)(?=>))` note the removal of escapes before `<` and `>` and then it works in the Insider's Build as of this date.

[And the `PCRE2` mode has been deprecated since the original question. So you do not need that option anymore, PCRE2 will be used automatically if needed.]

---

There is a similar bug when using search/replace with newlines and the replace just literally inserts a `$1` instead of the capture group's value.  This bug has been fixed in the latest Insider's Build, see [multiline replace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964578/how-to-swap-two-words-in-visual-studio-code-with-a-find-and-replace/57965045#57965045) and [issue: newlines and replace with capture groups](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80667).

But I tried your regex in the Insider's Build and it has the same result as you had before - it inserts the literal `$1` instead of its value.  It appears to be a similar bug but due to the regex lookarounds.

So I tried a a simpler, but I think still correct, regex without the lookarounds:

`^(#include\s+<)([^\.\/]+?)(>)`

and replace with `$1EASTL/$2.h$3` and it works as expected.

[image: search replace demo: no lookarounds].

Comment: Tried editing your answer but it's only a small typo so I'm not allowed to change it... you've missed the escapes in the code before "should be changed to:"