# How to swap two words in Visual Studio Code with a find and replace?

Tags: replace, visual-studio-code

The project I'm working on has a number of yaml files, where all the instances of `lat:` and `long:` need to be swapped, since the data is incorrectly labeled.

So for instance, the following:

```
- lat: "-82.645672"
  long: '44.941747'
  title: "Item 1"
- lat: "-82.645744"
  long: '44.940731'
  title: "Item 2"
- lat: "-82.645744"
  long: '44.940731'
  title: "Item 3"
- lat: "-82.646599"
  long: '44.941441'
  title: "Item 4"
```

Would need to look like this:

```
- long: "-82.645672"
  lat: '44.941747'
  title: "Item 1"
- long: "-82.645744"
  lat: '44.940731'
  title: "Item 2"
- long: "-82.645744"
  lat: '44.940731'
  title: "Item 3"
- long: "-82.646599"
  lat: '44.941441'
  title: "Item 4"
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to swap these two words globally. I looked at the plugins that are available, but they only seem to work with the current file you're editing, and when highlighting only a couple of words (i.e. like this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidmart.swap-word). I was looking into using regex as a possible solution, but can only find ways to reorder words on the same line. Is there a regex that can be used in a find and replace to swap two words that can get applied to all files in a project?

Comment: why not use a small python program that does this. or write a simple awk, sed script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap words across files (see end to swap words in one file easily):

Try this regex:

`^(-\s+)(lat)(.*)(\n\s*)(long)`     // I made a small change here

and replace with:

`$1$5$3$4$2`

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKauKX/7).

This works perfectly fine for me in the find/replace widget but **not** in the search/replace across files panel.  Why?  See this "resolved" issue:  [issue: regex search and replace](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58374).

The issue seems to indicate it was provisionally "fixed" but it doesn't appear that it has been.

I was going to open a new issue but found this from earlier this week: [issue: capture groups don't work when regex includes newline](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80667) .  So hopefully it will be fixed this iteration.

I am happy to report that this bug has been **fixed in the Insiders Build 2019-09-16**!!  Demo below in Insider's Build:

[image: search/replace with newlines and capture groups now working]

---

To swap words in a single file only, you can use this extension I wrote: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) and this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(lat)|(long)",        
    "replace": "${1:+long}${2:+lat}",  // swap here
    "isRegex": true
  }
}
```

There is no reason you couldn't make that swap 3+ words in some sequence you want.

`${1:+long}` is a conditional which says if there is a capture group 1, replace it with the text `long`.

Comment: Thanks! That's the type of regex I'm looking for, it's just it looks like it doesn't work with VS Code's regex find + replace. I'm going to try to see if I can get that sorted out why it's not finding + replacing properly...

Answer (score 1):

You can use only *replace* feature.
If you are using Windows, the shortcut is ctrl+h.

1. `ctrl+h`, replace *lat* to *dummy*
2. `ctrl+h`, replace *long* to *lat*
3. `ctrl+h`, replace *dummy* to *long*

Answer (score 0):

With the [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules) extension

```
  "replacerules.rules": {
    "Swap lat-long 1": {
      "find": ["lat","long"],
      "replace": ["XYZ","ABC"]
    },
    "Swap lat-long 2": {
      "find": ["XYZ","ABC"],
      "replace": ["long","lat"]
    }
  },
  "replacerules.rulesets": {
    "Swap lat-long": {
        "rules": [
            "Swap lat-long 1",
            "Swap lat-long 2"
        ]
    }
  }
```

Then execute command: `Replace Rules: Run Ruleset...`

Comment: It doesn't appear that "Replace Rules" extension works across files?

Answer (score -3):

Dude.
Remember the algorithm to swap 2 strings?

```
temp=str1
str1=str2
str2=temp
```

1. replace "long" with "TEMP".
2. replace "lat" with "long".
3. replace "TEMP" with "lat".

Thats it.